# Geulah Blessing in the Amidah

Tags: shemoneh-esrei, messiah

The seventh ברכה of שמנה עשרה is the blessing of גאולה.

The blessing begins ראה בעניינו (some add נא in between).

When ראובן was born, לאה said כי ראה ה' בעניי.

The usage likely comes from תהילים קי"ט-קנ"ג, which begins ראה עניי וחלצני.

My question is, are there any sources that, in whatever manner, relate ראובן (by tribe, name, or person) to this blessing.

Note: As one side point, it doesn't say ראה עניינו or ראה את עניינו but rather ראה בעניינו (as when the Torah provides the etymology for ראובן albeit also in other places) and if we assume the source verse is indeed תהילים קי"ט-קנ"ג, it seems (although I am no expert) that ראה עניינו or ראה את עניינו may have been more appropriate.

Comment: Can you add the posuk when leah says כי ראה ה' בעניי.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that Leah was very distressed with what was happening and that there was a bit of favouritism to Rochel, which made Leah upset and distressed. When the gemara in megillah is talking about why certain brachos are connected in Shemenoh Asrei, Rashi, comments that's what is bracha all about, since it right at the start of the Amidah and we speak about redemption later on. So Rashi explains that this bracha is a request to take us out of our own distresses, which when Leah is distress she retorts and says Hashem has seen my affliction. (Which fits very nicely to what happened to Revuen that he was the firstborn, but that transferred over to Yosef but instead of being distress he instead didn't want to kill him rather protect from that danger- Food for Thought).